# Using swipe and also select/touch

Tags: android

I have an app which I want to be able to swipe right and swipe left, but also select a position on the screen and do something on that seletion.

The problem I am having is that the touch events DOWN,MOVE,UP are being processed prior to the onSwipeLeft/Right and the event is being consumed. What I really need to know is if the swipe event will happen during the onTouch event. I can then ignore the selection and let the system process the swipe.

```
IVProgress.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        public void onSwipeLeft(){
            firstDateToDisplay.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            setDayTypes();
            updateTextViews();
            drawLines();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight(){
            firstDateToDisplay.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);
            setDayTypes();
            updateTextViews();
            drawLines();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.onTouch(v, event);
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the help of library.please go through the given library

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

i have also implemented like this